# Creating a Role Using a Modal Window

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, modal-dialog

using this code, a user can create a role for himself for a certain currency, but here's the problem, if you enter a command and open a modal window, but accidentally close it and open it a second time on a new one, it gives an error or creates this role twice I will be grateful if you help

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
     ModalBuilder,
      TextInputBuilder,
       TextInputStyle,
        ActionRowBuilder,
         EmbedBuilder,
          ButtonBuilder,
           ButtonStyle,
            StringSelectMenuBuilder,

  } = require('discord.js');
  

  const database = require('../../database');
  const { name } = require('../../events/exp');

  const roleSettingsButton = require(
    '../../buttons/role/roleSettings.js'
    );

  const removeRoleButton = require(
    '../../buttons/role/roleDelete.js'
    );
  
  async function createRole(roleName, roleColor, guild, creator) {
    const newRole = await guild.roles.create({
      name: roleName,
      color: roleColor,
      reason: 'Создание личной роли',
    });
  
    const botMember = await guild.members.fetchMe(); // Получаем объект GuildMember для бота
    const botRole = botMember.roles.highest;
    await newRole.setPosition(botRole.position - 1);
  
    const creatorMember = await guild.members.fetch(creator.id);
    await creatorMember.roles.add(newRole);
  
    return newRole;
  }
  
  async function sendRoleInfo(interaction, roles) {
    if (!roles || roles.length === 0) {
      await interaction.reply({
        content: 'У вас нет личных ролей.',
        ephemeral: false,
      });
      return;
    }


    let roleInfo = 'Информация о ваших личных ролях:\n';
  
    for (const role of roles) {
      roleInfo += `\nНазвание: ${role.name}\nЦвет: ${role.hexColor}\nID: ${role.id}\nПозиция: ${role.position}\n---`;
    }
  
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Информация о личных ролях')
    .setColor('#00ff00')
    .setTimestamp();
    let index = 0;
    for (const role of roles) {
        index++;
        embed.addFields(
            { name: '#', value: `**${index.toString()}**`, inline: false },
          { name: 'Информация', value: `<@&${role.id}>`, inline: true},
          { name: 'цвет', value: `${role.hexColor}`, inline: true},
          { name: 'ID', value: `${role.id}`, inline: true},
          { name: 'Позиция', value: `${role.position}`, inline: true},
        );
      }

    await interaction.reply({
    embeds: [embed],
    ephemeral: false,
  });
  }

  function generateRoleSelector(roles) {
    const options = roles.map(role => ({
      label: role.name,
      description: `ID роли: ${role.id}`,
      value: role.id
    }));
  
    return new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
      .setCustomId('roleSelector')
      .setPlaceholder('Выберите личную роль для настройки')
      .addOptions(options)
      .setMaxValues(1);
  }
  module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName('role')
      .setDescription('Управление, информация и создание личных ролей')
      .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
        subcommand
          .setName('manage')
          .setDescription('Управление личной ролью'))
      .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
        subcommand
          .setName('info')
          .setDescription('Информация о личной роли'))
      .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
        subcommand
          .setName('create')
          .setDescription('Создать личную роль')),
                  filepath: __filename,
    async execute(interaction) {


      const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
      let isModalConfirmed = false;

      switch (subcommand) {
        case 'manage':
            const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
              .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('settings')
                  .setLabel('Настройка роли')
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('delete')
                  .setLabel('Удалить роль')
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
              );
          
              const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
              .setColor(0x000000)
              .setTitle('Панель управления ролями')
              .setDescription('Выберите действия.')
              .setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL());
  
          await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow], ephemeral: true });

            interaction.client.on('interactionCreate', async (buttonInteraction) => {
              if (!buttonInteraction.isButton()) return;
            
              switch (buttonInteraction.customId) {
                case 'settings':
                  roleSettingsButton.execute(buttonInteraction);
                  break;
            
                case 'delete':
                  removeRoleButton.execute(buttonInteraction);
                  break;
            
                default:
                  console.error('Неизвестный customId:', buttonInteraction.customId);
              }
            });
            break;
            case 'info':
              database.getPersonalRoleFromDB1(interaction.guild.id, interaction.user.id, async (role_ids) => {
                if (Array.isArray(role_ids) && role_ids.length > 0) {
                  const personalRoles = await Promise.all(role_ids.map((role_id) => interaction.guild.roles.fetch(role_id)));
                  await sendRoleInfo(interaction, personalRoles);
                } else {
                  await sendRoleInfo(interaction, []);
                }
              });
              break;
            
        case 'create':

        const requiredCoins = 1;
        const userBalance = await database.getUserBalance(interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id);
      
        if (userBalance < requiredCoins) {
          await interaction.reply({
            content: `У вас недостаточно монет для создания личной роли. Требуется ${requiredCoins} монет.`,
            ephemeral: true,
          });
          return;
        }

          const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('createRoleModal')
            .setTitle('Создать личную роль')
            .setComponents(
              new ActionRowBuilder().setComponents(
                new TextInputBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('roleName')
                  .setLabel('Название роли')
                  .setPlaceholder('Введите название для личной роли')
                  .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
                  .setRequired(true)
                  .setMinLength(1)
                  .setMaxLength(100)
              ),
              new ActionRowBuilder().setComponents(
                new TextInputBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('roleColor')
                  .setLabel('Цвет роли')
                  .setPlaceholder('Введите HEX-код цвета для роли')
                  .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)
                  .setRequired(true)
                  .setMinLength(7)
                  .setMaxLength(7)
              )
            );
          await interaction.showModal(modal);

          const modalSubmitInteraction = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
            filter: (i) => {
              if (isModalConfirmed) return false;
              console.log('Ожидание отправки модального окна');
              console.log(i.fields);
              return true;
            },
            time: 120_000,
          });
      
          const roleName = modalSubmitInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue(
            'roleName'
          );
          const roleColor = modalSubmitInteraction.fields.getTextInputValue(
            'roleColor'
          );
        
        try {
        await modalSubmitInteraction.deferUpdate();
        isModalConfirmed = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка при обновлении интеракции:', error);
      }
      
        try {
            const guild = interaction.guild;
            const newRole = await createRole(roleName, roleColor, guild, interaction.user);

            // Списываем монеты с баланса пользователя
            await database.updateUserBalance(interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id, userBalance - requiredCoins);

            database.savePersonalRole(guild.id, interaction.user.id, newRole.id, () => {});
      
            await modalSubmitInteraction.followUp({
              content: `Личная роль "${roleName}" создана с цветом ${roleColor}.`,
              ephemeral: false,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Ошибка при создании роли:', error);
            try {
              await modalSubmitInteraction.followUp({
                content:
                  'Ошибка при создании роли. Проверьте правильность введенных данных.',
                ephemeral: true,
              });
            } catch (followUpError) {
              console.error('Ошибка при отправке follow-up сообщения:', followUpError);
            }
          }
          break;
        // Здесь добавьте другие case для других подкоманд
        default:
          console.error('Неизвестная подкоманда:', subcommand);
      }
    },
};
```

Here is the error that is thrown

```
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
at async REST.request (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
at async ModalSubmitInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:200:5)
at async Object.execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot discord\commands\custom\role.js:225:9)
at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot discord\index.js:164:3) {
```

requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } },
rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
code: 10062,
status: 404,
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1097142541985529982/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTA5NzE0MjU0MTk4NTUyOTk4Mjo1TnBSVWVMZE9WaXNKMmpjS1BMZzY3S052Y1dNempuNjlJczlpRmZrYVBuaXZQQktOWVozMG1TdVlvbTU4bXloODU4dlRENTlTV1ViS0lzdXVXWk8xUndtc2dZZEhheFhFZTlWUHd6enNEWUlxZzZhOGh3VW5SeUo0Rm1sZjVzZw/callback'
}